# What is a black hole microstate?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, black-holes, entropy, string-theory

What is the most generally accepted way of defining what a black hole microstate is?  On a related note, I don't believe there is a Wikipedia page on the topic.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147052/discussion-on-question-by-kevin-njokom-high-school-level-definition-with-math); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Word Summary:

It seems the most general way of thinking about black hole microstates involves constructing black hole solutions in supergravity. These solutions provide a description of the black hole's geometry and other fields. From these solutions, the entropy of the black hole can be obtained through the area law.

On the other side of the coin, we can study a string gas. These strings get excited. The entropy of the gas can then be calculated by counting the microscopic arrangements or configurations of this string gas.

The entropy obtained by both the supergravity solutions approach and the string gas approach match.

$S = 2 \pi \sqrt{N Q_1 Q_5}$

This is in particular for the case of low energy five-dimensional Type II string theory (supergravity) and the gas of (1,1), (1,5), (5,1), and (5,5) strings.

This agreement suggests that the entropy of a black hole indeed corresponds to the microscopic arrangements of the soliton string gas.

Take as references:

- [Maldacena](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9607235.pdf)
- [Zwiebach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521880327)

-Black hole construction and calculation of entropy by area law

```
 - Zwiebach page 518 third paragraph

 - Maldacena (2.38), (2.39)

 - Zwiebach (22.138)
```

-Calculation of entropy from string gas

```
 - Energy of brane containing gas of strings

      - Maldacena (1.10)

 - Maldacena (4.5)
```

Match! -Zwiebach (22.140), (22.142) & Maldacena (4.5), Maldacena (2.39)

```
 Conclusion:
```

- Configurations of soliton string gas

The calculations in the references can be followed and replicated with *relative ease* using Mathematica.

Comment: Please leave feedback on -1 so I know what's going on.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/420006)

Comment: @Miyase Thank you for the feedback. I will be updating this answer in a few minutes to include the essential parts.

Comment: @Miyase I have now made edits to the answer

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a black hole microstate is more or less just "whatever happens in, on, and around a black hole at the Planck scale". There is no consensus beyond this, except that considered collectively, the microstates need to reproduce the macrostates of black hole thermodynamics. The details of the microstates are entirely dependent on one's choices of theory and model.

If you choose to work in string theory, it is probably fair to say that ["black hole microstates ... are quantum-mechanical bound states of fluctuations of fundamental objects of string theory like strings and branes"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.11732).

But even just within string theory, there is a confusing variety of perspectives - at least it's confusing to me. The model of black hole that is receiving the most attention has changed across the years. At one time (late 1980s, early 1990s?) it might have been a "long string" model, in which the black hole is one long self-interacting string tangled up in itself. Then in the mid-1990s, modeling a black hole as a gas of strings stuck to a brane or two (which you write about in your answer) came to the fore. Later, AdS/CFT duality would have encouraged the perspective according to which the holographic dual of a black hole in Anti de Sitter space, is a plasma in the field theory on the boundary. And in "M(atrix) theory", you might describe a black hole as a web of many D0-branes connected by string.

I guess my point with respect to string theory is that there are multiple ways to build a black hole out of charged extended objects, that are "generally accepted" in the sense of being a valid construct within the theory. These days, the most popular kind of stringy black hole are probably black holes associated with low-dimensional theories like JT gravity, in which the "Page curve" (describing entropy over time of an evaporating black hole and its radiation) is being derived for the first time. But that just represents where research is currently focused, it doesn't mean that the older models of stringy black hole are no longer considered valid.

Comment: Please see my new answer. I could not fit it into a comment so I just wrote it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could not fit this into a comment, so here I am writing another answer "off the cuff".

There is some talk in [Mathur's article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.11732) about tuning the coupling. I am taking this to mean we are going from gas to liquid in the interaction sense.
It seems that because of the nature of the geometry, tuning toward the liquid state collapses the system into a black hole. This is because G is proportional to the string coupling. The counting is then done in the liquid state for an ensemble of BPS states.  I am taking as a point that they are bound states of constituents that are probably interacting.

On JT gravity. I have now taken a moment to look at the action of the theory. I suspect after obtaining the equations of motion, all sorts of games could be played.
I want to believe that the standard idea around evaporation holds except in an easier arena to handle things. I have not done this yet but I guess the business involves looking at exploiting pair creation and energy conservation in a strongly curved space.

The hope is that after pair separation an infallen particle with negative energy adds negative energy packets to the black hole reducing its size. The escaped particles form a weak spectrum. If this happens over time the black hole
evaporates to essentially nothing. In fact, it would seem that in the specific JT case, one identifies a black hole eom and focuses on the action (using action here now in the English sense) near the horizon. Maybe I should try to do something like this one of these evenings before I go to bed . ..

So I am going to speculate that the page curve is looking at the time evolution of the entanglement entropy of the Hawking radiation and the black hole. Perhaps it is easier to look at the time evolution of the density matrix at each time step,
and then compute the difference in entanglement entropy at each time step to get the change in entanglement entropy. Maybe at some point, I should try to implement this something like this in Mathematica.

**Terminology**

*Extended supersymmetry*

-- Going beyond N = 1:  One supercharge generator resulting in one superpartner also known as minimal supersymmetry

-- For example N = 4: four supercharge generators resulting in four superpartners

*BPS*

-- BPS states are states that preserve some supersymmetry

-- So $Q_\alpha |BPS⟩ = 0$

-- Consequence: invariant index

*BPS bounds*

-- Statement : E ≥ |Z|

-- Z is the central charge

Bound state

-- Take as example theory with a confining potential

-- Compute the energy and associated states

-- The associated states are the bound states

-- Bound states arise because the confining potential traps the constituents

-- External energy would have to be added to the system to have them escape